# WCF NetTcp Binding - changing TransferMode from Buffered to Streaming

Tags: .net, wcf, streaming

We have a WCF self-hosted server and several Winforms and Web clients all using NetTcp bindings with TransferMode=Buffered. We have all sorts of DataContracts, using lots of methods with arbitrary objects as parameters.

We now have to implement a service which accepts a Stream as a parameter. If I change TransferMode to "Streaming" on the server and the clients, will this break existing contracts? Or do they just behave as before, that means, they use Buffered mode as long as there is no parameter of type "Stream" passed?

Quick smoke tests seems this might be the case (the application behave like before) - but I need to be sure that there are no consequences which I might oversee.

Thanks for any advice!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just changing the TransferMode from buffered to streamed will not break the contracts, it's only going to effect your binding.

Basically the TrasferMode **buffered** will load in your memory all the data before sending it to the other endpoint while **streamed** will start sending chunks of data as soon as they are ready and will reduce the amount of memory you need to send great quantity of byte.

Here you can see some restrictions on using streaming message but it should not affect your current situation from my understanding

https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/drnick/2006/03/31/how-to-enabling-streaming/